# NServiceBus 4 configuration error using .XmlSerializer()

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

Using NSB 4 with this configuration:

```
Configure.With()
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()
```

Gives this <strike>error</strike> warning

```
'NServiceBus.ConfigureXmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(NServiceBus.Configure, string, bool)' 
is obsolete: 'Please use 'Configure.Serialization.Xml()' instead. Will be treated as an 
error from version '5.0'. Will be removed in version '6.0'.'
```

How should `Configure.Serialization.Xml()` be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Configure.Serialization.Xml()` anywhere before the `Configure.With()...` block.

Or don't. XML is the default, so you don't need that block at all unless you want to use one of the overloads to set a specific setting.

These are new settings that are slowly taking the place of the fluent config with the goal of making the configuration order-agnostic and introducing sensible defaults so that self-hosting becomes a lot easier.

At some point in the future, you'll be able to use something like `Configure.CreateBus()` if you just want the defaults!

Comment: Nice one, thanks David.  Glad to see the config is getting smoother too.